# How to find a line of best fit of the form $y=ax$?

Tags: statistics, regression

We have the following points:

$$ (0,0)(1,51.8)(1.9,101.3)(2.8,148.4)(3.7,201.5)(4.7,251.1)(5.6,302.3)(6.6,350.9)(7.5,397.1)(8.5,452.5)(9.3,496.3)$$

How can we find the best fitting line $y=ax$ through the points? My calculator has the option to find the best fitting line $y=ax+b$ through these points, which is:

$$y \approx 53,28x + 0.37$$

How can I find the best fiting $y=ax$? It seems to me we can't just remove the $0.37$ without compensating in the $a$?

Comment: This is supposed to be a Mathematics site.

Comment: [Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression): Regression analysis, a statistical technique for estimating the relationships among variables. Unlucky, mate.

Comment: -1: Off topic. Statistics is not mathematics

Comment: Flagged this post for moderator attention.

Comment: @Did Thank you, you don't need to. It's getting enough attention as it is.

Comment: Voted to reopen.  Statistics questions are on topic here (e.g. 2,879 questions are currently tagged [statistics]).

Comment: I have deleted the unnecessary and hostile comments, this was completely inappropriate.  I have also reopened this question since I do not agree with the closure "not constructive."  The pedantic debate about whether or not statistics is mathematics can be taken elsewhere, but as far as this site is concerned, statistics is one of the most commonly used tags, with nearly 3000 questions asked.  If you believe that this would get a better answer on Cross Validated, then please flag the post for moderator attention.  Closing the question as "Not constructive"  does not make sense.

Comment: My first comment is at is because of the OPs first comment (which was deleted). Although I believe in what I said, I wouldn't have said it as I feel it is inappropiate, if unprovoked. Just letting y'all know.

Answer (score 5):

To find **a** best fit, you must first decide what you judge it by. A simple method would be, wanting the least ("vertical") distance from your predicted values. But because one usually doesn't care whether it's above or below it, the square of the distance is used. This is of course holds info about a single point only. So the sum of these can be used instead.

So that for example, if you wish to fit your $n$ data points of the format $(x_i,y_i)$ to a function $y'=ax$ - That is to every point $x_i$, you predict $a x_i$ and get $y_i$ instead. Therefore the above goodness function is described by

$$ f(a) = \sum_n (y_i - a x_i)^2$$

This is a function of your parameter $a$ and can be optimized for it:

$$\frac{df}{da} = 0 \Rightarrow \sum_n 2x_i(a x_i - y_i) = 0 \Rightarrow a = \frac{\sum_n x_i y_i}{\sum_n x_i^2}$$

Edit: Actually for this function, $y'=ax$, the distance to the line and the vertical distance are the same up to a constant factor, which leads to the same result. Lucky, I guess... =)